# jQuery binds to one fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, file-upload

I am using following tutorial to change the CSS for default file Upload control [LINK](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle)

I managed to implement it for one control But i need it to work for four file upload controls on the same page.

Problem is that it implement this only for one control.

```
   // For Custom FileUpload
    $("input[type=file]").filestyle({
        image: '<%= ResolveUrl ("~/images/browse.png") %>',
        imageheight: 22,
        imagewidth: 82,
        width: 128
    });
```

I change it to work for Class it still implementd only for the first control only

```
$(".fileUpload").filestyle({
    image: '<%= ResolveUrl ("~/images/browse.png") %>',
    imageheight: 22,
    imagewidth: 82,
    width: 128
});
```

HTML CODE SAMPLE

```
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="row-lbl-wrapper"> <span class="row-req">*</span>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="row-label" Text="CV:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadCV" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn-upload" onclick="btnUploadCV_Click" ValidationGroup="Careers" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnProcessData" runat="server" Text="Process Data" OnClick="btnProcessData_Click" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblImageMSG" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip tooltip-override" title="Allowed file formats are .pdf, .doc and .docx.">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" CssClass="tooltip-img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/tooltipgreen.png" />
    </div>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvF1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Careers" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="row-validate" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="row-lbl-wrapper"> <span class="row-req">*</span>

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="row-label" Text="CV:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn-upload" onclick="btnUploadCV_Click" ValidationGroup="Careers" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Process Data" OnClick="btnProcessData_Click" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip tooltip-override" title="Allowed file formats are .pdf, .doc and .docx.">
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" CssClass="tooltip-img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/tooltipgreen.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Cant we change it to change Style for all file upload control. Example how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first debug if

$(".fileUpload")

returns multiple objects. Also review the resulting page in browser, whether the css class is present where you would expect it to be.

I reviewed the plugin you're using and it seems it supports multiple objects.